# How to install SafeAreaView to my project with react-native version 0.48.0?

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, react-native, react-native-ios

#### Here is the problem:

I want to install SafeAreaView to my project to adapt iPhone X screen, and I do not want to upgrade react-native version to 0.50.1 which contains the **SafeAreaView** component, now my react-native version is **0.48.0**, there is also a JS only version that is available as an npm module, react-native-safe-area-view.

- https://github.com/react-community/react-native-safe-area-view

I installed it with

> npm install react-native-safe-area-view --save

then I run my project with xcode, It shows errors

#### Here is the errors:

error: bundling failed: ambiguous resolution: module /Users/dongfanggouwu-xiong/WebstormProjects/untitled/index.js tries to require react-native, but there are several files providing this module. You can delete or fix them:

- `/Users/dongfanggouwu-xiong/WebstormProjects/untitled/node_modules/react-native-safe-area-view/node_modules/react-native/package.json`
- `/Users/dongfanggouwu-xiong/WebstormProjects/untitled/node_modules/react-native/package.json`

there are two react-native module, one is in react-native-safe-area-view, and I don't know how to fix it, I have wasted much time on it, and tried a lot ways to find a solution.

So is there anyone who has the same problem about iPhone X adaption in react-native with me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally, I found a solution.
If you’re not on React Native 0.50+ yet, you can use react-navigation’s SafeAreaView.

```
import { SafeAreaView } from 'react-navigation'
```

and the react-navigation version must be the newer version which contains SafeAreaView, as far as i know, react-navigation version has to at least 1.00@beta 16, so maybe you need to upgrade your react-natigation to a newer version.